# I am getting Ribbon1.xml file not found exception when I double click the addin.vsto file

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2013, ribbonx

I have created an outlook vsto addin. It is not installing on some machines, but on some machines it doesn't work.So, for debugging I double clicked the .vsto file.And it gave me the following exception:

> Name: CustomPane_outlookAddIn From: file:///C:/Program Files
>   (x86)//Outlook Plug-In/CustomPane_outlookAddIn.vsto
>
> ************** Exception Text ************** System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException: Downloading
>   file:///C:/Program Files (x86)//Outlook
>   Plug-In/Ribbon1.xml did not succeed. ---> System.Net.WebException:
>   Could not find file 'C:/Program Files (x86)//Outlook
>   Plug-In/Ribbon1.xml'. ---> System.Net.WebException: Could not find
>   file 'C:/Program Files (x86)//Outlook
>   Plug-In/Ribbon1.xml'. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not
>   find file 'C:/Program Files (x86)//Outlook
>   Plug-In/Ribbon1.xml'.    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32
>   errorCode, String maybeFullPath)    at
>   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)    at
>   System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path,
>   FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length,
>   Boolean async)    at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest
>   request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri,
>   FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)    at
>   System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)    --- End
>   of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem
>   next)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.DownloadAddIn(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()

I get this error on both the machines where the addin loads properly and where it doesn't load in outlook.I do have a ribbon1.cs and ribbon1.xml file in my vsto project.But, I am not referencing it in my ThisAddin.cs file at all.So, why is it trying to load that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there was a ribbon1.xml file in my solution.And it was automatically being picked by the vsto file.I removed that file which solved the problem.